# Is there a way to not waste 4 panels for hand signs or hand gestures in a comic book?

Tags: creative-writing, comics, script

[image]

Now, I made a question on how to merge comic panels, but what about the very specific case where the moving parts stay relatively static, or rather they don't change position, and they move while holding their x y z position like the picture above. In that situation I feel like it's a lot more tricky and I am trying to figure out how to not waste 4 panels while depicting for example 4 gestures. Could you show some examples?

Comment: If you're not limited by a fixed panel layout (e.g. each row split in 4 equal panels), then you could just split one regular panel into four small ones to show the gestures. Or even overlay a small row of 4 panels over another panel, as if you're zooming in on the hands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You could draw all of the gestures superimposed on each other. Hard to read, but if you're emphasizing the intensity of the movement instead of the accurate depiction of the gestures, this works.

Or you can draw all of the action in a single panel with the gestures in different positions. You could guide the reader's eye with speech bubbles so they know these gestures are happening in a sequence, or simply positioning the gestures in such a way that there is a tempo or rhythm to them. Of course the way it's drawn would imply that the hands are slightly changing position with each gesture, so this might be something you want to consider.

[image]

This is not a perfect example, but reading this, you would not think that the character suddenly has five fists. Replace the fists with hand gestures and you get the idea.